# Joi: validate array element depending on index

Tags: javascript, joi

In Joi is there any way to validate elements of an array based on its index? I have this:

```
const schema = Joi.array().items(
      Joi.object({
        a: Joi.string(),
        b: Joi.number()
      })
    )
```

and i want "a" required only for first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can combine [array.ordered](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayorderedtype) with [array.items](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayitemstypes):

```
const schema = Joi.array()
    .ordered(Joi.object({
        a: Joi.string().required(),
        b: Joi.number()
    }))
    .items(Joi.object({
        a: Joi.string(),
        b: Joi.number()
    }));
```

This way, the array must have the first item as the object you defined with **a** required, and the subsequent items wouldn't have the **a** required.

This validation will pass:

```
schema.validate([{ a: '123', b: 10 }, { a: '123', b: 10 }])
```

And this one will fail:

```
// ValidationError: "[0].a" is required
schema.validate([{ b: 10 }, { a: '123', b: 10 }])
```

It could be a little bit tricky if you want to validate some other element than the first one.